# AWS BOTO - find volume ID of an ec2 instance using tag

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

We have defined tags for our ec2 instances. We would like to use the python boto module to fetch a list of volumeId's or EBS volumes by using tags. Tags have already been created for the instance. We would like to use the name tage which in this case is "dev" and list the EBS volumes associated with it.
Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to try to write some code to try to solve the problem and then post a specific question if that code is not working.  If you are having problems getting started, here are a few tips.

The first thing you will need to do is find all of the instances that have a specific tag of the form `name=<somevalue>`.  In boto, you would use the `filter` parameter of the `get_all_instances` method to accomplish this.  Something like this should work:

```
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'name': ['somevalue']})
```

This will return a list of `Reservation` objects which match the query.  Inside the `Reservation` object is an attribute called `instances` which is a list of `Instance` objects.

For each of the `Instance` objects in that list you will want to find the EBS volumes associated with the instance.  Again, you will want to use the `filters` parameter to accomplish this.  In this case the filter name you want is `attachment.instance-id`.

```
volumes = conn.get_all_volumes(filters={'attachment.instance-id': [instance.id]})
```

Where `instance` is one of the `Instance` objects returned from the first call.  This will return a list of `Volume` objects for all of the EBS volumes currently attached to `instance`.

I hope that helps.  Try to write the code and then if you run into specific questions, ask them here.